# Get column all values in one array using Eloquent

Tags: arrays, select, eloquent

I want to get all values of a specific column in a single array. Looking for a Eloquent function that can do it.

Something like this:

```
Model::select('id')->where('type', 'user')->asArray()
```

And expected result is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent doesn't have a single built-in function to do this.  However, you can use `map` to flatten the Collection of `Model` objects into an array:

```
$coll = Model::select('id')->where('type', 'user')->get();

// Pull the id out of each member of the collection
$coll = $coll->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->id;
});

// Convert collection to an array
print_r($coll->toArray());
```